# How to run conductor jar on different port, other then 8080?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-conductor

I am running conductor jar using command, java -jar conductor3.3.4.jar so conductor is up and running on port 8080 now I want to run the above command again but with different port java -jar conductor3.3.4.jar so conductor --server.port=8081. But it is not working, I have also tried with passing a application.properties file. Please help me on this.

I tried with commands java -jar conductor3.3.4.jar so conductor --server.port=8081 also tried by passing application.properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is a script I used to test running conductor on a custom port

run.bat (windows)

```
SET CONDUCTOR_VER=3.11.2
SET PORT=8888
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/netflix/conductor/conductor-server/%CONDUCTOR_VER%/conductor-server-%CONDUCTOR_VER%-boot.jar --output conductor-server-%CONDUCTOR_VER%-boot.jar 
java -jar conductor-server-%CONDUCTOR_VER%-boot.jar --server.port=%PORT%
```

If this does not work then maybe the port is not open or another application is using it. You can check this by running

netstat -aon

Details here
https://inevent.com/blog/tech-and-trends/how-to-check-open-ports-for-live-streaming.html